# How to fix unexpected white line in bottom of CardView in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, android-cardview

I have a `CardView` like this, but there is a white line at the bottom where there shouldn't be. Any idea what could be causing this?

[image]

Here is the code!

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/home_list_listview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:listitem="@layout/home_list_item"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Are there more rows in your list below the Tables row?

Comment: nope. it's just a listview set by an array adapter with 4 elements. If i switch to Landscape View, I don't see this white line (I have to scroll to see all 4 items in landscape though)

Comment: I am programmatically setting the height of each element in the listview. So the list view's total height / 4. I'm guessing the issue is that when the listview's pixel count isn't evenly divisible by 4, I have an extra 1-2 pixels that don't get colored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am programmatically setting the height of each element in the listview. So the list view's total height / 4. I'm guessing the issue is that when the listview's pixel count isn't evenly divisible by 4, I have an extra 1-2 pixels that don't get colored.

Agreed.

I would recommend not using `ListView`, but instead just having four rows as views in the vertical `LinearLayout`, each with a weight of 1 to evenly divide the space.

Or, adjust your size calculations to take the leftover pixels into account, allocating them to rows as needed.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I had originally, but I had to change it to a ListView to achieve the ripple effect across the whole list item per http://stackoverflow.com/a/28309358/891242

I also also using Gradle product flavors to build this app in two different ways (where the list will have different # of items/colors/text/icons depending on the flavor, so having a listview helps here anyway.

Comment: @user891242: Ripples aren't really tied to `ListView`.

Comment: added the size calculations, and it worked great!

For the ripple issue, I had difficulty getting the ripple to appear over the linear layout that contained both an imageview and textview. Using a ListView with drawselectorontop did the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

I thinks that line is a bug from compat of CardView. If you set cardCornerRadius to 0dp that line disappear. This problem only happens on api <21.